# How to use pear FILE package example

Tags: php, file, pear

Can someone give me example how to use installed pear package, specifically FILE package. I'm php beginner and have never worked with pear so I'm interested in how to use any package after installation...I just call classes and functions from package it self? Second thing that interests me, can I just include downloaded package where ever I need in my files and use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some very good examples linked to from [the official File documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.filesystem.file.php), and yes you pretty much just call those functions and methods in that package from your own code.

The answer to your second question is also "Yes" :-) You can include that package in your code where-ever you need it.